# Sum of the series $\sum_{k=2}^\infty (-1)^k (\frac{x+1}{2})^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the sum of the series for those values $x$ of
$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty (-1)^k \left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)^k$$
I know that
$$a=\frac{x+1}{2}$$ and $$r=\frac{-x-1}{2}$$
When I plug these values into the formula $$S_n=\frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r},$$ I get $$S_n=\frac{(x+1)(2^n-(-x-1)^n)}{(2^n)(x+3)}$$ However, I am not sure if I did it correctly. Would this be right?

Correction:
$a=\frac{x^2+2x+1}{4}$
So $Sn=\frac{x^2+2x+1}{2x+6}$ and it is correct when -3 < x < 1

Comment: The formula holds for $S_n$ when starting the sum from $k=0$, not $k=2$. So you have to just subtract the first 2 terms (when $k=0$ and $k=1$) from your current $S_n$. Also, the formula for $S_n$ holds if $|r|<1$. You need to verify this by considering which values for $x$ would satisfy that condition.

Comment: For the infinite sum to converge, you need $\vert r\rvert = \lvert \frac{x+1}{2} \rvert < 1$. Then, you get $\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n = \frac{r^2}{1-r}$.

Comment: @Xoque55 The formula for $S_n$ is true for all real $r$

Comment: @Diego Except $r=1$, at least unless you want to argue about taking the limit to define it by continuity and so on.

Comment: @Diego You're right, thank you. I got ahead of myself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it says $\displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^\infty$ rather than $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty$, the first term is $a= (-1)^2 \left( \dfrac {x+1} 2 \right)^2$.  The common ratio is exactly what you had, $r=\dfrac{-x-1}2$.  The sum of the **infinite** geometric series with first term $a$ and common ratio $r$ is given by
$$
a + ar + ar^2 + ar^3 + \cdots = \frac a {1-r}.
$$ 
The expression you gave, $S_n = \dfrac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$ is for a **finite** geometric series with $n$ terms.  You said
$$
a = \text{something}
$$
and
$$
r = \text{something}
$$
but you omitted
$$
n=\text{something},
$$
and that's because in this problem there is no $n$ because the number of terms is infinite.

Comment: A crucial point, though: "The sum of the infinite geometric series with first term $a$ and common ratio $r$  is given by [...] *provided $\lvert r\rvert < 1$*."

Comment: Would that mean that the correct answer is $a=\frac{x^2+2x+1}{4}$
and $Sn=\frac{x^2+2x+1}{2x+6}$ and it is correct when -3 < x < 3?

Comment: Correction: I meant -3 < x < 1 @michaelhardy

Comment: @BB8 : The notation $S_n$ seems to assume there is such a thing as $n$, so I wouldn't write it that way.  Other than that, you've got it. $\qquad$